# Installing Ionic framework on CentOS

Tags: centos6, ionic-framework

I'm using CentOS 6.3 running on Windows 7. I would like to use Ionic to build apps for iPads and android tablets. I was wondering if I need any special configurations to setup my system in order to use Ionic Framework. I couldn't find instructions on their website. Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find all infos about the setup of your machine:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html

I suggest you to take a look to this post about the [Ionic Box](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-vagrant-android/). Is a virtual machine ready to use that helps a lot windows users. Ionic Box works with [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) and [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

Keep in mind that **without** an OSX machine you **can't** develop an iOS app for iPad.